# »Es gibt« im Plusquamperfekt

Tags: pluperfect

I need to use *es gibt* in the pluperfect, for an essay that I’m writing, but I’m not sure how to do it.

- Present: *Es gibt etwas*
- Past: *Es gab etwas*
- Pluperfect: ?

*Es war etwas gegeben* sounds wrong to me, but I don’t just want to write *Es gab,* because then the tenses won‘t match. How do I do this?

Comment: Voting to close because the answer can easily be found in your average grammar book.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are right that the past participle of *geben* is *gegeben*, but the auxiliary verb to use with it is not *sein*, [it is *haben*](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/geben#Deutsch). Therefore the correct form is:

> Es hatte gegeben.

Answer (score 10):

*Es war etwas gegeben* is past passive voice.

- Present: Es gibt
- Past: Es gab
- Present perfect: Es hat gegeben
- Pluperfect: Es hatte gegeben

*Es hatte etwas gegeben* is pluperfect.